# I can't write into database with embebed form in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm handle embebed form with symfony2 but I have this error:

> Entity of type GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\Transportista has identity through a foreign entity GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\EmpresaExterna, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\Transportista'. In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.

I have two entities named EmpresaExterna.php and Transportista.php where I have a foreign key from transportista to exmpresaexterna, So I make a embebed form to insert into both tables but I can do this.

This is my code for EmpresaExterna.php:

```
<?php 

namespace GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
*@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\EmpresaExternaRepository")    */

class EmpresaExterna
{
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=80) 
*/

protected $nombreEmpresa;

/**
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=60) 
*/  

protected $comuna;

/**
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=60) 
*/  

protected $correo;

/**
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=20) 
*/  

protected $telefono;

/**
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=60) 
*/  

protected $ciudad;

/**
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=100) 
*/  

protected $direccion;

/**
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=20) 
*/  

protected $rut;

/**
* @ORM\column(type="string", length=20) 
*/  

protected $numeroSidrep;
```

Obviously included the getters and setters.

For Transportista.php:

```
<?php 

namespace GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EmpresaExternaRepository")
*/
class Transportista
{
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\EmpresaExterna")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nombreEmpresa_id", referencedColumnName="nombreEmpresa")
*/

protected $nombreEmpresa;
```

My forms are, RegistroTransportistaType.php, and RegistroEmpresaExternaType:

```
<?php
// src/Gestionresiudos/EmpresaExternaBundle/Form/RegistroResiduoType.php

namespace Gestionresiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistroTransportistaType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('nombreEmpresa', new RegistroEmpresaExternaType())
        ->add('registrar', 'submit')
        ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{

    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Gestionresiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\Transportista'));

}

public function getName()
{
    return 'gestionresiduos_empresaexternabundle_registrotransportistatype';
}
}
```

RegistroEmpresaExternaType:

```
namespace Gestionresiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistroEmpresaExternaType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('nombreEmpresa')
        ->add('comuna')
        ->add('correo')
        ->add('telefono')
        ->add('ciudad')
        ->add('direccion')
        ->add('rut')
        ->add('numeroSidrep')
        ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{

    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Gestionresiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\EmpresaExterna'));

}

public function getName()
{
    return 'gestionresiduos_empreasexternabundle_registroempreasexternatype';
}
}
```

My controller is this:

```
public function nuevoTransportistaAction(Request $request)
{       
    $transportista = new Transportista();
    $empresaExterna = new EmpresaExterna();

    $formulario = $this->createForm(new RegistroTransportistaType(), $transportista);
    $formulario->handleRequest($request);

    if($formulario->isValid())
    {
        //guardar la info en la base de datos
        //setear el nombre de la empresa
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        // $transportista->getNombreEmpresa();
        $em->persist($transportista);
        $em->flush();
        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('inicio')); 
    }

    return $this->render('EmpresaExternaBundle:Default:registroTransportista.html.twig', array('formulario' => $formulario->createView()));   
}
```

I find another post that explain similar but they used onetomany whit inversedBy into table.

Finally this is my form in twig:

```
    {#src/Gestionresiduos/SolicitudIngresoBundle/Resources/views/Default/solicitaringreso.html.twig #}
{% extends '::frontend.html.twig' %}

{% block id 'usuario' %}
{% block title %}Registro de nuevo transportista{% endblock %}

{% block article %}
<h1>{{ block('title') }}</h1>

{{ form_start(formulario)}}
    {{ form_errors(formulario)}}

    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.nombreEmpresa, 'Ingrese el nombre de la empresa') }}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.nombreEmpresa)}}</span><br>
    </div>

    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.comuna, 'Ingrese comuna') }}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.comuna)}}</span>
    </div>


    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.correo, 'Ingrese dirección email') }}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.correo)}}</span><br>
    </div>


    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.telefono, 'Telefono') }}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.telefono)}}</span><br>
    </div>


    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.ciudad, 'Ingrese ciudad') }}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.ciudad)}}</span><br>
    </div>

    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.direccion, 'Indique dirección')}}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.direccion)}}</span><br>   
    </div>

    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.rut, 'Ingrese el rut de la empresa') }}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.rut)}}</span><br>
    </div>

    <div>
    {{ form_label(formulario.nombreEmpresa.numeroSidrep, 'Ingrese el número SIDREP') }}
    <span>{{ form_widget(formulario.nombreEmpresa.numeroSidrep)}}</span><br>
    </div>

     <div>
    {{ form_widget(formulario.registrar) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(formulario) }}
{{ form_end(formulario)}}

{% endblock %}
{% block aside %}{% endblock %}
```

Sorry for the big explanation. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are persisting your parent entity (`Transportista`) without persisting your child entity (`EmpresaExterna`) first. As it has no `id` yet (that's a new / non-managed one), Doctrine can't map it.

Try this in your controller:

```
    $em->persist($transportista->getNombreEmpresa());
    $em->persist($transportista);
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: Yes, you do not need both flushes

Comment: You persist the main entity and by using cascade={"all"} or cascade={"persist"} it will save the related entities for you. You may need to add a line to your addMethod too but I can't remember off the top of my head and don't have PC access at the minute.

Comment: Thank you a lot guys. I apreciatte your answers. Grettings

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code:

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\EmpresaExterna")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nombreEmpresa_id", referencedColumnName="nombreEmpresa")
*/

protected $nombreEmpresa;
```

To this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\EmpresaExternaBundle\Entity\EmpresaExterna", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nombreEmpresa_id", referencedColumnName="nombreEmpresa")
*/

protected $nombreEmpresa;
```

This will allow you to just persist the main entity and all related entities will be saved too.

```
$em->persist($transportista);
```

You may need to add further code into your addMethod for the main entity for the nombreEmpresa relationship.